# Как считать информацию из текстового файла JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня есть в одной папке файлы html, css, js и txt. Мне нужно чтобы при открытии html файла на странице при нажатии кнопки выводилось содержимое файла txt. Т.е. он должен читаться сам, без выбора этого файла пользователем через imput или перетаскивания его куда-либо. Считанная информация разбивается на строки и передается в js файл и там уже обрабатывается. Сам txt файл должен только считываться, изменяться он не будет.
У меня абсолютно нет идей. Node js я не понимаю как работает, а AJAX при попытке считать файл выдает httpRequest.status = 0.
Все что я нашла это получение файла через imput(не подходит), запрос через AJAX(не работает) и Node js(я не понимаю как он работает)
UPD: Мне не нужно чтобы файл отображался где-либо на странице, мне нужно просто получать из него данные и уже с ними работать.

Comment: Покажите код кнопки, где выполняется ajax запрос. Файл txt лежит на сервере?

Comment: Это все работает на сервере или же файлы лежат в локальной папке?

Comment: Файлы лежат в локальной папке, я вообще без понятия как работать с сервером и нужен ли он тут.

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs/

Comment: Я не понимаю как работает node js. Я пишу код в js файле(как раз тот что в ссылке) и он мне выдает Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at testhtml.html:43:12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно попробовать использовать теги `<embed>` или `<object>` и с их помощью загрузить текстовый файл в html. Сначала попробовать чтобы файл отобразился, а потом уже можно будет грузить в скрытый элемент.

И если файл грузится, то можно попробовать получить его содержимое через JavaScript.

UPD: Как выяснилось такой вариант сработал бы на сервере. С локальными файлами не работает. По той же причине почему не работает AJAX - браузер не дает загружать такие файлы из-за настроек безопастности.

Так что вероятней всего вариант остается только один - переделать txt файл в файл JS. Например все данные в файле сделать как значение одной переменной. И потом подлюкчить этот JS файл как обычный JavaScript и использовать уже переменную в своем коде.

Comment: Можете привести пример? допустим просто файл test.txt или что-то подобное?

Comment: А если текст в txt задумывался большим? Т.е. таким, что не влезает в переменную.

Comment: @DaraHessesh тогда разбить его на строки или абзацы.  И каждый фрагмент сохранить ка отдельную переменную, а лучше как элемент массива.